# Subtraction of dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1: 
1   2   3   4   5
5   2   3   4   3
3   4   2   1   
2   3   2       
4   1           
1               

df2: 
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   2   1
```

Here, first rows, "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" are the column names for both the dataframes

Excel formula I want to calculate is:

```
=IF(A2="","",A2-$G2)
```

Here A, is the first cell for data frame df1, G2 is the first cell for dataframe df2

```
Output: 
3   2   -1  2   2
1   0   -2  -1  
0  -1   -2      
2   1           
-1
```

How do I do this in R?

Reproducible example:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1, text='
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  5  2  3  4  3
2  3  4  2  1 NA
3  2  3  2 NA NA
4  4  1 NA NA NA
5  1 NA NA NA NA')

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, row.names=1, text='
  X1 X2 X3  X4 X5
1  2  3  4   2  1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example data: (You did not provide any)

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
df2 <- mtcars[7,1:5]
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
#        Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21
```

code:

```
t(apply(df1,1,function(x){x - unlist(df2)}))
#                  mpg cyl disp   hp  drat
#Mazda RX4         6.7  -2 -200 -135  0.69
#Mazda RX4 Wag     6.7  -2 -200 -135  0.69
#Datsun 710        8.5  -4 -252 -152  0.64
#Hornet 4 Drive    7.1  -2 -102 -135 -0.13
#Hornet Sportabout 4.4   0    0  -70 -0.06
```

Answer (score 1):

Make both dataframes same dim (nrow and ncol), then use subtraction:

```
df1 - matrix(rep(unlist(df2), ncol(df2)), nrow = ncol(df2), byrow = TRUE)
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  3 -1 -1  2  2
# 2  1  1 -2 -1 NA
# 3  0  0 -2 NA NA
# 4  2 -2 NA NA NA
# 5 -1 NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(t(t(as.matrix(df1))-unlist((df2))))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3 -1 -1  2  2
2  1  1 -2 -1 NA
3  0  0 -2 NA NA
4  2 -2 NA NA NA
5 -1 NA NA NA NA

sweep(df1,2,unlist(df2))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3 -1 -1  2  2
2  1  1 -2 -1 NA
3  0  0 -2 NA NA
4  2 -2 NA NA NA
5 -1 NA NA NA NA
```